# Execute a SQL statement to set a PostgreSQL parameter setting in each "database session"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have created a new Symfony 7.x project with `symfony new ...`. I have installed the `symfony/orm-pack`. Doctrine, Dbal the ORM etc. are working.

I am using PostgreSQL.

What I want to achieve now is, to set a config variable on every database session in Postgres.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET

So every database operation will have this setting before any other query is executed.

For illustration, this is a typical log entry from the system I am migration this from:

```
2024-03-07 14:10:36.937 UTC [1600] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT set_config($1, $2, false)
2024-03-07 14:10:36.937 UTC [1600] DETAIL:  parameters: $1 = 'customer.user_id', $2 = '1'

2024-03-07 14:10:36.960 UTC [1600] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT * ...
```

I evaluated [event listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/events.html#doctrine-lifecycle-listeners) for this, but it seems they do not cover my use case.

How can I accomplish this in an idiomatic "Symfony way"?

Comment: What's a "database session" in this context? A request? A transaction? Any SQL statement?

Comment: You probably want to implement a middleware: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-bundle/en/2.11/middlewares.html

Comment: A database session is basically everything that comes after a successful connection (request). A session can have multiple transactions.

Comment: Middlewares look promising :D

Comment: A request might not be the same as a "successful connection". But you'll probably want to go with "request". Good luck with middelwares. Here you have Symfony's Doctrine bundle docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/DoctrineBundle/middlewares.html